# Drag the application phonegap

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

I wonder how I do that the scroll PhoneGap does not have this 
in my application when I drag the mouse on the application, it will go 
up or down, as I do Ileave it fixed? I posted pictures of what is 
happening, thanks! 
http://postimage.org/image/pa2kyvvwb/ 
http://postimage.org/image/gf8cnrjsx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this script, but then you'll have to handle scrolling yourself if you page is bigger than the screen:

```
//Prevent dragging of canvas on iOS
$(document.body).bind('touchmove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: That script is assuming jQuery, but can be easily converted

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be on every apple device the same. This is not an PhoneGap feature. When draging a website on my mac mini the same happens. So you'll have to do it programmatically in objectiv-c. Maybe this works

```
CGSize scrollableSize = CGSizeMake(320, myScrollableWidth);
[myScrollView setContentSize:scrollableSize];
```

Comment: Thank you for responding dude, I'm new to obj-c could tell me where I put this code? Thank you!

Comment: i am new to obj-c too, but maybe you try it in the method which will be called first. Would try it in the ViewController.m in "ViewDidLoad"....